# Using Azure API Management Services ,remove extra space from JSON request

Tags: azure-api-management

I am using azure API Management Services to log request and response of api's.

Now I have a requirement to remove extra space from incoming JSON request.I tried so many things like 'find and replace' and replace filter but not able to achieve it.

```
eg: Incoming request
body.FullName ="XYZ   ABC"

<set-body template="liquid">
 {    
   "Id": "{{body.Id}}",
   "FullName":"{{body.FullName]}}"       
 }
</set-body>
```

As you see above in FullName between XYZ and ABC has three spaces.
My requirement is to remove extra spaces between them as you see in below example.

```
Final output would be :
{
"Id" : 12
"FullName" : "XYZ ABC"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do do that only for certain properties, then try:

```
<set-body template="liquid">
 {    
   "Id": "{{body.Id}}",
   "FullName":"{{body.FullName | split: " " | join: " "}}"       
 }
</set-body>
```

Seems there is no better way to do that in liquid.

If you want to do that in whole body without analyzing it's structure, then:

```
<set-body>@(Regex.Replace(context.Request.Body.As<string>(), @"\s+", " "))</set-body>
```

Alternatively you could parse entire body as JObject and iterate over is recursively fixing up every property value.

Comment: it will not work when there are more than 2 spaces
    eg: "FullName" : "XYZ   ABC" //3 spaces
according to your answer output woud be:
2 spaces merge into 1 space and plus remaining one space wont be altered.Total would be 2 spaces
    eg:"FullName" : "XYZ  ABC" //2 spaces

Comment: Indeed. Updated with a fix.